# Loop over file names

Tags: matlab

I have some data files of the same dimension, I have a program in MATLAB for the analysis of data from a single file. I want to merge all the data from the files, one after the other so that I can analyze it all together. How can i write a loop such that it goes over all the files?

Answer (score 4):

```
fls = dir( fullfile( folderName, '*.mat' ) );
data = cell( 1, numel(fls) );
for ii = 1:numel(fls)
    data{ii} = load( fullfile( folderName, fls(ii).name ) );
end
```

`data` now holds all your data

Answer (score 0):

You may get list of files by [dir function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) and the loop is easy.